# Removing sub list by comparing its elements with elements in all other sub lists in Python

Tags: python, list, element

I am storing the start and end coordinates of line segments together with some attributes in a list of lists with the form.

I want to remove from my main list each sub list where the pair of coordinates (x1 y1 , x2 y2) already exist in my list but reversed (x2 y2 , x1 y1)

My code is:

```
lines=[[(x1, y1), (x2, y2), id1, id2],[(x2, y2), (x1, y1), id2, id1]] #random example 
lns=[ [l[0], l[1]] for l in lines] #make a list only with the node coordinate pairs
for line in lines:
if [line[1],line[0]] in lns: 
    lines.remove(line)
```

This code results in removing some of the elements that I want (not all of them though) and some that shouldn't be removed. Any idea what I may be missing?

Comment: You need to change your `if` condition and add the IDs in the end: `if [line[1],line[0],line[2],line[3]] in lns:`

Comment: @VasilisG. With your suggested condition I can omit the list comprehension that produces the "lns" list and iterate in my "lines" list.
Nevertheless, I still have some lines that shouldn't be there. To check if they "pass" the condition, I applied the exact same code once again in the resulting list and I got the correct result. But it is not how it should work. I still can't imagine what goes wrong.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and the desired output of those?

Comment: You can find a .txt file and a .py file with my code here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sit0p37xo4n40rh/AABbQ6rIAZjCTjNuPYhf3gMDa?dl=0). 
The lists have two elements instead of four, so only the point ids. I did not include the the points coordinates for simplicity. The exact same process can be applied on the point ids instead.

Comment: I forgot to mention about the desired output, the ids  in the list represent lines start and end point ids. All the lines exist in the list defined from start to end point and the reverse.  So all the pair of ids are twice included. I need the final list to have half of its elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With few adjustments in the initial code and after fixing the bug this code gives the correct output:

```
lines=[[(x1, y1), (x2, y2), id1, id2],[(x2, y2), (x1, y1), id2, id1]]
for line in lines:
    if [line[1],line[0], line[3],line[2]] in lns: 
         lines.remove([line[1],line[0], line[3],line[2]])
```